# Adding StructFields to an existing schema

Tags: scala, loops, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I created a class "Attribute". Each class object has a name, a datatype and a boolean value (nullable or not). All objects are saved to a ListBuffer.

I try to create a schema from the list and pass each value to the StructField(). Initiating works but unfortunately no further items are getting added to the schema.

```
def create_schema_from_attr_list(attr_list: ListBuffer[Attribute]): StructType = {
  // Get first list item and initiate schema
  var schema = StructType(StructField(attr_list(0).name, attr_list(0).data_type, attr_list(0).nullable) :: Nil)

  // Add remaining items
  for (i <- 1 until attr_list.length) {
    schema.add(attr_list(i).name, attr_list(i).data_type, attr_list(i).nullable)
    println("Test " + attr_list(i).name.toString())
  }        
  return schema
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `add` method doesn't modify the `schema` in place. Think it a little bit like the string concatenation methods in Java.

You can make your code behave as you want by simply reassigning the result of the addition to `schema` itself:

```
def create_schema_from_attr_list(attr_list: ListBuffer[Attribute]): StructType = {

  // Get first list item and initiate schema
  var schema = StructType(StructField(attr_list(0).name, attr_list(0).data_type, attr_list(0).nullable) :: Nil)

  // Add remaining items
  for (i <- 1 until attr_list.length) {
    schema = schema.add(attr_list(i).name, attr_list(i).data_type, _list(i).nullable) // here
    println("Test " + attr_list(i).name.toString())
  }        
  return schema

}
```

Another solution, probably simpler, is to just process the items within the `ListBuffer` to make a `StructField` out of each attribute and pass the result directly to the `StructType` constructor (which accepts the `ListBuffer`'s parent class `Seq` as a parameter).

```
def attributeToStructField(attr: Attribute): StructField =
  StructField(attr.name, attr.data_type, attr.nullable)

def attributesToSchema(attrs: ListBuffer[Attribute]): StructType =
  StructType(attrs.map(attributeToStructField))
```

If you are not familiar with the `map` function: it's defined over all collections and takes a function `A => B` which turns a `ListBuffer[A]` into a `ListBuffer[B]` (or any other collection, for that matter). You'll encounter this kinds of *higher-order functions* all other the place in Scala and Spark.

Answer (score 2):

You initiated the `schema` but you never assigned the added `structfield` back to `schema` inside the loop. That's why your added `structFields` are not reflected in the initiated `schema`.

You should use `DataTypes` api for flexible creation of `schema`. Following is my suggestion. Hope it helps

```
def create_schema_from_attr_list(attr_list: ListBuffer[Attribute]): StructType = {
  // create bufferedlist of structfield
  val bufferFields : util.ArrayList[StructField] = new util.ArrayList[StructField]
  // Add structfields
  for (i <- 0 until attr_list.length) {
    bufferFields.add(DataTypes.createStructField(attr_list(i).name, attr_list(i).data_type, attr_list(i).nullable))
  }
  DataTypes.createStructType(bufferFields)
}
```